# Run a command when any cron job fails instead of just sending an email

Tags: cron

Is there some way to call a script of my own instead of just sending an email when any cron job fails?

Comment: Look into wrapping your job and checking $? or if it's a script, check $? yourself...

Comment: But I'd need to wrap all cron jobs, and whenever someone adds a new job they'd have to remember to wrap again. It'd be much better to have a general solution.

Comment: If you're looking for a more-general solution, please edit your Q and subject line to indicate that. Right now it implies 'a' / one cron job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that with Vixie cron, which is standard on most systems nowadays, but there is a very workable alternative.

What you do is setup a special user towards which all emails from cron are redirected by setting `MAILTO`, in the crontab file, to that user. And for that user you make some `.procmailrc` entry or entries that execute the alternative command if a mail got received for a failed command. You might need to do some parsing of the mail to determine whether an error was encountered, or enforce that programs that have zero exit do not write to stdout.